# SQL запрос в phpMyAdmin выдает правильное значение, а в PHP нет

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Данный запрос в phpMyAdmin отрабатывает правильно и выдает нужную цифру, а если выполнять его через скрипт php, то он постоянно выдает цифру 1. Прикладываю скриншот, где видно, что цифры 1 в таблице нет вообще. Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

```
$db = Db::getConnection();

    $sql = 'SELECT `id_seed_product` FROM `seed_and_seed_parameter` ORDER BY `id_seed_and_seed_parameter` DESC LIMIT 1;';
    $result = $db->prepare($sql);
    return $result->execute();
```

[image: скрин таблицы]

Comment: Вы получаете код успешности выполнения операции. А что вы ожидали получить?

Comment: Ожидал получить значение 'id_seed_product'

Comment: Это множество значений, а не одно.